# Simple Python script not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

I am trying to learn Python. This is my first time writing Python script. All I am trying to do is take a string as an input and print it if it is not 'exit'. But it is showing various errors.

```
def main():
    while True:
        data = input('Please enter a string');
        if data == 'exit': 
            break
        else:
            print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The errors were as follows. First time it said:

> unexpected EOF while parsing

Second time it said:

> nameerror: name 'asd' not defined

Comment: What do you mean by "first time"? Is that the error the above code generates? My guess is "no".

Comment: second time my input was 'asd', first time the input was 'first time'(sorry for not being creative)

Comment: The error generates after i give the input.

Comment: by first time i meant i ran the code twice. each time with different input.

Comment: You've tagged this `Python 3-x`, but that error message only makes sense if you're using some Python 2 version, in which case `input` tries to `eval` what you type.  You may not be running Python 3 even if you think you are.  Could you add `import sys` and then `print(sys.version)` to the start of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indentation is off.  It should be:

```
def main():
    while True:
        data = input('Please enter a string');
        if data == 'exit': 
            break
        else:
            print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Python takes indentation very seriously (in fact, that is how it knows what goes with an if-statement, function declaration, etc.)

**Edit:**

My post above was geared towards your question using Python 3.x (after all, that is the tag you gave).  Since you are not using 3.x, but 2.x instead, then your function should be like this:

```
def main():
    while True:
        # Use raw_input instead so input is not evaluated
        data = raw_input('Please enter a string');
        if data == 'exit': 
            break
        else:
            print data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thanks, but that is not the issue, my indentation is off only in stackoverflow because I copy pasted. In my actual code the indentation is working. Its only after i give my input, then the error occurs

Comment: @eddard.stark - Then I think you are using Python 2.x when you believe you are using 3.x.  The code I gave runs fine in Python 3.x.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the confusion. It seems that I am using python 2.7.4. I didn't know. I am really sorry.

Comment: @eddard.stark - No problem.  Just remember Python 2.x and 3.x are VERY different.  They are almost incompatible.  Thus, it is vital to know which one you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You'll get an error because the function "input" expects an intenger.
Use raw_input to recover the text you type.